# Bypassing the login page in Guacamole 1.2.0

Tags: guacamole

I have set up Guacamole 1.2.0 on Ubuntu server 20.04 which works great. Is it possible to bypass the login page in Guacamole 1.2.0 using the auth-noauth component from a previous Guacamole release? The release notes in 1.2.0 say the older components are compatible. I used guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.tar.gz, but I still get the Guacamole login page come up.

This is what I did.

1. Downloaded `guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.tar.gz`
2. Extracted the .jar file using `tar xzf guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.tar.gz`
3. Copied the file `guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.ja`r to `/etc/guacamole/[extensions,lib]`
4. Amended my `guacamole.properties` file to:

```
      guacd-hostname: localhost
      guacd-port:     4822
      user-mapping:   /etc/guacamole/noauth-config.xml
      auth-provider:  net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.auth.noauth.NoAuthenticationProvider
      noauth-config: /etc/guacamole/noauth-config.xml
```

5. Created a new `noauth-config.xml` file with the contents

```xml
<configs>

    <config name="myconfig" protocol="rdp">
        <param name="SVxxxx01" value="rdp-server" />
        <param name="port" value="3389" />
    </config>
</configs>
```

6. I then copied guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar to the classpath directory I created `cp guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar /var/lib/guacamole/classpath`

Any advice and tips to bypass the login page will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sure enough changing the version of the extension worked! guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar is not compatible by default but if you change the .jar extension to .zip, extract, edit guac_manifest.json to replace "0.9.14" with "1.2.0", re-zip (or replace), and optionally rename the whole thing guacamole-auth-noauth-1.2.0.jar (to avoid confusion) you end up with a working extension provided all other standard configuration steps are followed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the plugin is correctly loaded. The tomcat logs (catalina.out) should write something like
"INFO  o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "My guacamole extension" loaded.".

If it is not loaded, check if the location of the plugin is correct. Normally, the plugins are located in GUACAMOLE_HOME/extensions directory. You may see the default values for GUACAMOLE_HOME here: https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html

I usually create extension directory in ~tomcat/.guacamole/extensions, but you should be fine with any other location specified in the documentation.

Comment: Hi mnkolic, thank you for your reply. I am new to Guacamole, Linux etc. I don't see anything in my most recent tomcat logs regarding the plugin. How else do I check that the plugin is correctly loaded please? Are the steps I listed correct to make it work?

Comment: My GUACAMOLE_HOME directory has these files: /etc/guacamole$ ls
'[extensions,lib]'   guacamole   guacamole.properties   guacamole.war   noauth-config.xml
     I don't see an extensions directory, should there be one?

Comment: You should place guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar into extensions directory. You have to create manually "extensions" directory; according to the docs, /etc/guacamole/extensions should be fine. If that does not work, I would suggest creating directory ~tomcat/.guacamole/extensions. Note: it may be ~tomcat8 or ~tomcat7 depending on your distribution, use tab for autocompletition in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. I created the extensions directory within /etc/guacamole/. I did an **ls** to make sure guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar was in the directory and can confirm it is. Unfortunately this didn't work, I am still getting the Gucamole web GUI login screen. I then created the extensions directory in /etc/tomcat9/guacamole/extensions and can confirm the guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar file is in there too. I restarted both tomcat9 and guacd, but still get the Gucamole web GUI login screen. Any further advice you can provide is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the config in my guacamole.properties and noauth-config/xml files are correct? FYI, my POC project is 3rd party users will connect to a Palo Alto clientless VPN via their browser, click on an icon for the RDP access (hence using Guacamole as my RDP gateway), bypass the Guacamole web GUI login page and the access the RDP server. Look forward to hearing from you again.

Comment: Seems like guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar is not compatible after all with the latest 1.2.0 version : ( I found this is my syslog -    ERROR o.a.g.extension.ExtensionModule - Extension "guacamole-auth-noauth-0.9.14.jar" could not be loaded: Extension "Disabled Authentication (DEPRECATED)" is not compatible with this version of Guacamole.

Comment: You may try to change the version of the extension. There is a file "guac_manifest.json", where you will find property "guacamoleVersion". Try to change it to the version of the Guacamole you have installed. There is always a chance it will not work due to the incompatibilities, but it is worth trying. The noAuth extension is not so complex, so there is a big chance it will work, and even if not, it shouldn't be complex to fix it.